# Display image from a URL in django

Tags: image, django-models, url, cs50

I am currently working on a project that allows the user to provide an image URL for an auction listing. However, I am unable to get the image to be displayed on the browser despite getting the URL from my Listings model and including it in the src attribute of the image tag. Any idea how to actually solve this problem? I have attached the problem and the code for my different files.

[Image not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTBip.png)

index.html

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>
    <div class="listing-grid">
        {% for listing in listings %}
            <div class="listing-container">
                <div class="original_lister">
                    Listed by <span class="user">{{listing.0.user}}</span>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img src="{{listing.0.image}}" alt="listing image">
                </div>
                <div class="listing-info-container">
                    <div class="list_title">
                        <a href="{% url 'listing' listing.0.title %}" class="listing-link">{{listing.0.title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="separator">&#183;</div>
                    <div class="category">
                        {{listing.0.category}}
                    </div>  
                </div>
                
                <div class="price">           
                    ${{listing.1}}               
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    Description: {{listing.0.description}}
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py for my index route

```
from .helpers import get_total_bids, is_original_lister, get_current_price

def index(request):
    listings = Listing.objects.filter(is_active = True)

    listing_price_pairs = get_current_price(listings, Bids)
            
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "listings": listing_price_pairs,
    })
```

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser): 
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"


class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
    
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        ('Fashion', 'Fashion'),
        ('Toys', 'Toys'),
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
        ('Home', 'Home'),
        ('Jewelery', 'Jewelery'),
        ('Entertainment', "Entertainment"),
        ('Books', "Books"),
        ('Pets', 'Pets'),
        ('Others', 'Others')
    ]  
    
    category = models.CharField(max_length = 20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=None)
    image = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="listing")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Listing {self.pk}: {self.title} | {self.category}|  Listed by: {self.user.username}"


class Bids(models.Model):
    bid_amount = models.FloatField()
    total_bids = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Bid ID: {self.pk} | {self.bid_amount} "
    

class Comments(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comment")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment ID {self.pk} | {self.comment} | Listing ID: {self.listing.pk}"

class Closed_Listings(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.winner} won {self.listing}"


class Watchlist(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)  
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.listing} in {self.user}'s watchlist"
```

app's urls.py

```
from os import name
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("create_listing", views.create_listing, name="create_listing"),
    path("watchlist", views.watchlist, name="watchlist"),
    path("categories", views.categories, name="categories"),
    path("categories/<str:category>", views.category, name="category"),
    path("<str:title>", views.listing, name="listing")
]
```

project's urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("auctions.urls"))
]
```

Comment: Is this image part of your own project and has to be served as a static file **or** is it an image on another site that you want to just link via that url?